# How do I name my APIs in API store (WSO2)? Is there any naming conventions or best practices?

Tags: api, wso2, naming-conventions, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to create and publish APIs from different service providers and publish them as a common solution (under a single API store). Currently, I am trying to make the API names simple and descriptive like **action(verb)-onwhat(noun)**. For example I am having a API that gets a list of FOOs, I would name the API as **List-FOO**. So simple right?

But the real problem arises here. As I said I am doing it for multiple service provider, chances are I would have API to list the FOOs specific for another service provider too. Even I thought **service_provider-action(verb)-onwhat(noun)** like **ProviderA-List-FOO**.

But I dont think that would make sense if I want the store as a common one. Is there anything that I am missing or is there a better way to name the APIs in store to avoid these kinds of issue? Any help is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

based on the given requirement, I can suggest you define separate API packages for each service provider. for example, you can create new API for **ProviderA** and define all services of **ProviderA** as the **resource paths** under that API.

Comment: Thanks for the suggesstion. But even that I cannot do as I need to expose each service as API and not the service provider as API. because vendors need not subscribe to service providers but only to sercvices.

Comment: could you please elaborate on the services and service providers? for Ex, services : [List-Foo, Create-Foo, Update-Foo, Delete-Foo], service providers: [ProviderA,ProviderB], So all service providers are exposing all services?